# 多面体の頂点群もしくは平面群から三角ポリゴンメッシュの作成

Tags: c++, アルゴリズム, directx

3Dグラフィックスで凸型多面体を描画したいと考えています。
多面体はそれを囲む平面（境界無し）で定義されているため、順序を問わないのであればすべての頂点を取得することが出来ますが、三角ポリゴンメッシュをねじれ等なく作成するスマートな方法が分かりません。

Answer (score 1):

点群からメッシュを生成する[PCL](http://pointclouds.org/)という有名なライブラリがあるようです．
様々なアルゴリズムが実装されているので適当なものを用いれば良いかと思います．

簡単に紹介しているサイトがありました．
[点群からトリム面を作成(PCLライブラリ)](http://www.rccm.co.jp/icem/pukiwiki/index.php?%E7%82%B9%E7%BE%A4%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A0%E9%9D%A2%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%28PCL%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%29)

Comment: ありがとうございます。資料を漁ってみます。